# R current time in milliseconds

Tags: r

How can I get the current time in milliseconds? I tried the below without success:

```
> strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2022-05-14 19:42:53 CEST
```

Comment: Sys.time _is_ in milliseconds, just that the printing method suppresses those by default. as.numeric(Sys.time()) will display them (or see ?strptime for options to display them in the printed string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do get milliseconds by default on all operating systems, and (almost as the effective resolution is just a fraction less) microseconds on Linux and macOS -- but you *must enable the printing of it*.

##### Default R behaviour

```
> options(digits.secs=0) 
> Sys.time()             
[1] "2022-05-14 13:01:57 CDT" 
>
```

##### Changed to Six Digits

```
> options(digits.secs=6)
> Sys.time()
[1] "2022-05-14 13:02:54.038276 CDT"
>
```

I actually set this in my default `~/.Rprofile` to always have six decimals.

Answer (score 2):

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

#[1] "2022-05-14 11:01:17.928"
```